# Context Menu will not open

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a UWP app and I test it currently on the phone and on the desktop. In that App I have a Context menu defined in the data template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AccountTemplate">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Holding="AccountList_Holding"
                RightTapped="AccountList_RightTapped">
        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Uid="Edit"
                                Text="Edit"
                                Click="Edit_OnClick" />
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Uid="Delete"
                                Text="Delete"
                                Click="Delete_OnClick" />
            </MenuFlyout>
        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0, 12" >
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                           Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right"
                            Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"
                            Text="{Binding CurrentBalance, Converter={StaticResource AmountFormatConverter}}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Iban}"
                       Style="{StaticResource DeemphasizedBodyTextBlockStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And in the code behind:

```
private void AccountList_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
    var flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(senderElement);

    flyoutBase.ShowAt(senderElement);
}

private void AccountList_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
    var flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(senderElement);

    flyoutBase.ShowAt(senderElement);
}
```

Now I noticed that especially on the right click the context menu won't open always. After some tries I figured out that I have to click on one of the TextBlocks to get it work (and of course in there must be some text in it). Also it seems like he only gets the data context if click directly on a TextBlock.

How can I achieve that it will fire and get the datacontext when I click anywhere on the list item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add `ItemContainerStyle` to you `ListView` or `GridView`.

```
<GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And also set `StackPanel`'s `Background` property to `Transparent`.

Comment: I already had the HorizontalContentAlignment but added one for the VerticalContentAlignment aswell. It's definitly better now. But the cursor needs to be fairly on the list item to get the click. Funny enough, the click itself is registered and marked with a visual effect far earlier o.O